# What's so special about radians? (Differentiation)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It seems to me that radians have lots of very special properties that allow us to do maths with trigonometric functions. When I first came across radians, I was led to believe that they were designed purely to make finding areas and arc lengths of sectors more easy. But then I discovered that:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin x=\cos x$$
Clearly this only works when using radians. If you used degrees and found the gradient of $\sin x$ at $x=0$ you would get  that gradient $=\frac{\pi}{180}^{\circ}$. So my question is: why does differentiating $\sin x$ give you $cosx$ **when you are using radians**? What makes radians so special in this respect?

Comment: Heuristically, you can think of using radians as the most natural form of sin and cosine. The Taylor expansions are literally defined in radians, because its the most natural way. Changing to degrees results in a change of variables, because degrees aren't natural. They are a really bad approximation of a calendar year ;)

Comment: Radians are a natural measure of an angle. If you take a unit circle, the the angle in radians of a point is the distance measured on the unit circle (not the straight line distance) between $(1,0)$ and the point in question (in an anti clockwise direction).

Comment: I'll have a look at the linked question. I really wanted to know specifically why we need radians when we differentiate and intergrate, as in a proof or demonstration of that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter which unit for angles you use, the derivative of the sine will be *some* multiple of the cosine.

The radian measure is *chosen* as the angle measure that makes the proportionality constant $1$. If it was a different angle measure that did this we would be working with *that* as the natural angle measure instead of radians.

Geometrically think of the sine of a very small angle, that is, the ratio between short side and the hypotenuse in a very thin right triangle. We can scale everything so the hypotenuse has length 1; then the sine is simply the length of the short side.

So if we want $\sin'(0)=1\cdot\cos(0) = 1$ we had better choose our angle measure such that the measure of a *small* angle is close to the length of that short side.

Now, if we draw a circular arc next to the short side with the hypotenuse as the radius, until it reaches the extension of the *long* leg of the triangle, this will almost coincide with the short side -- and the thinner the triangle is, the better does it match.

And "arc length of a unit circle" is clearly additive on angles, so it will work as an angle measure. Therefore it is *the* angle measure that makes the derivative of the sine at 0 unity.

Comment: Ok, so its to do with the fact that radians is strictly a measure of arc length?

Comment: @user75473: It depends on what you're asking. I'm supposing that you take it as given that radians are _defined_ as arc length, and are asking why that definition happens to produce an angle measure with nice differential properties. If you have a _different_ definition of "radian", the answer won't necessarily involve geometry.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm asking. By using arc length we are comparing like for like when we compare the length of the short side to the length of the arc. That answers my question, thanks.

Comment: but we essentially are finding the *ratio* of the arc length to the radius, so the angle in radians is a *ratio* not a length

Comment: Ok, but if we are using a unit circle, then the small side can also be considered a ratio. So aren't we still equating equal things?

Comment: @user75473: Yes -- you can either define "radian measure" as "length of an arc of a unit circle" or "radius of the length of _some_ circular arc to the radius". It appears that Danimal prefers the second choice.

Answer (score 1):

to prove the differential of sin(x) is achieved using the fact that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{sin(x)}{x} = 1$$
to prove that we say that for a small enough absoulte(x) $$sin(x)\leq x \leq tan(x)$$
this is proved using a bit (complicated) geometry, that is only true assuming x is in radians. [image]

KH is sin(x)

the arc KA is x

and LA is tan(x)

this however is not a proof,
the full proof is a bit more complicated.

Comment: We can think of radian measure as the arc length of a unit circle. By the same token, we can think of degree measure as the arc length of a circle of radius $\frac{180}{\pi}$.

The limit of the ratio of to height of point $K$ to the arc length (in degrees) becomes
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{180}{\pi}\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$
implying that
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \frac{\pi}{180}$$
This is why (where $x$ is in degrees)
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin x = \frac{\pi}{180}\cos x$$